# What is this NUMA-aware allocation

Tags: parallel-processing

I came across NUMA-aware allocation in relation to improving the performance of the application. It is something related to Multicore programming. I know NUMA means non-uniform memory access but I am not aware of NUMA-aware allocation.

Do anyone know about this?

Comment: a NUMA aware app is an app that knows its system is NUMA and takes that into account when requesting resources in order to use them in the most effective way.

Answer (score 1):

NUMA aware allocation is basically the ability to allocate resources in a way such that the NUMA-properties of the system does not result in unnecessarily long commnication paths. I.e memory should be allocated in the RAM connected directly to the CPU where the process needing it runs, etc